# Python - Looping in different values and passing it into a variable

Tags: python

I have a Python script that pulls in all fields from JIRA. I have multiple projects within JIRA and the set of columns within each project is different. Hence I have the below script that works just fine.

```
## Login to Jira
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('login@login.com', 'password'), options={'server': 'https://company.atlassian.net'})

# Pulling Proj_A tickets

issues = jira.search_issues('project= Proj_A',maxResults=False) ## Get Proj_A tickets

## Create the full df by normalizing the output
issue_list = []
for i in range(len(issues)):
    result = json_normalize(issues[i].raw['fields'])
    result['issue_id'] = issues[i]
    result['issue_link'] = 'https://company.atlassian.net/browse/' + str(issues[i])
    issue_list.append(result)
final_issue_df_a = pd.concat(issue_list, axis=0, sort=True).reset_index()

# Pulling Proj_B tickets

issues = jira.search_issues('project= Proj_B',maxResults=False) ## Get Proj_B tickets

## Create the full df by normalizing the output
issue_list = []
for i in range(len(issues)):
    result = json_normalize(issues[i].raw['fields'])
    result['issue_id'] = issues[i]
    result['issue_link'] = 'https://company.atlassian.net/browse/' + str(issues[i])
    issue_list.append(result)
final_issue_df_b = pd.concat(issue_list, axis=0, sort=True).reset_index()

# Concatenating fields from the 2 projects into one single dataframe
Final_DF = pd.concat([final_issue_df_a,final_issue_df_b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This above code works just fine. Now I am trying to optimize the script wherein I am trying to pass a loop that has list of all projects as below:

```
project = [Proj_A,Proj_B,Proj_C..]
```

This gets passed to the first line

```
(issues = jira.search_issues('project=',maxResults=False))
```

and iterates each project and pulls in relevant fields that gets stored in the final Dataframe.

Could anyone assist. Thanks

Comment: What is the issue...I do not understand the question.

Comment: @Rakesh, I am trying to rebuild the above code, wherein I have list (let's says project) that contains all project names. Then pass values from this list instead of writing the same code for each project separately. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the project api to get a list of projects in JIRA. Then extract Project Name from each Project returned.

```
r = requests.get('https://<jira>/rest/api/2/project', auth=('username', 'password'), verify=False)

projects = r.json()

#Get name of each project 
for i in projects:
    print i['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
projects = ['Proj_A', 'Proj_B', 'Proj_C']
final_df_list = []

for project in projects:
    issues = jira.search_issues('project= '+project, maxResults=False)
    # Rest of the code processing the issues obtained above
    final_issue_df_x = pd.concat(issue_list, axis=0, sort=True).reset_index()
    final_df_list.append(final_issue_df_x)

Final_DF = pd.concat(final_df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```